# Why comp-op attribute not working in SVG for apply composite operation?

Tags: svg, composite

I want to apply a composite operation in my graphics rendering project in SVG.
my project uses src-Over, dst-out, dst-in, dst-over, etc... composite operation.
I dont want to use fecomposite, I found some help while searching on the Internet, but it didn't work even while I am running this code in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/MehulP/pen/oJZOeo?editors=1010).

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="simplecompop"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 480 360">
     <title>Simple Compositing</title>
     <g id="content">
        <circle cx="200" cy="160" r="50" fill="blue" opacity="0.7"/>
        <rect x="180" y="150" width="160" height="100" fill="red" opacity="0.8" comp-op="src-atop"/>
     </g>
</svg>
```

my Desire output is as below.

[image]

And what I am getting as output when I am executing this code is as below.

[image]

My question is why I am not getting a composite operation with "comp-op" attribute.  Again, I don't  want to apply fecomposite, if  any, other  easy way then please suggest.

Below is the all composite operational output that I found on  the Internet.

[image]

Comment: @RobertLongson I have edited my Question for your query, I get reference from that all composite operation output picture and so I assume "src-atop" should clip the rect.

Comment: What makes you think that `comp-op` is a valid attribute?  Why are you expecting it to work?

Comment: I found the above code from http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/abstractsvgopen/
"7.1 Compositing" section so I am assuming this code and comp-op should work.

Comment: The SVG 1.2 full specification was abandoned.

Comment: @RobertLongson When I am running above code in browser, comp-op is not working but when I am converting this svg file into png using online converter I am getting right output in png what I want with composite operation, so,again my question is why it is not working in browser and why it is working while converting to png? 
Steps: Save this code as test.svg, Drag->Drop in https://svgtopng.com/ , Download converted file.

Comment: I already answered that, the SVG 1.2 specification was abandoned. Why an online converter would implement an abandoned specification is something only the author of that online converter would know.